# Mixing Knockout with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I'm creating a commenting system with knockout.js and I'm having some issues with getting the templating working with our existing jQuery functions.

One example is with the dates comments are created.  I wrote a jQuery function that causes the data to turn from `5-5-2012` to `2 Days ago`. For example:

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Comments">
        <li data-bind="attr: { id: Id }" class="Comment">
           <div data-bind="text: DateCreated" class="prettyDate"></div>
           ...
        </li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
              $(".prettyDate").prettify();
          });
    </script>
```

With this code, when I add a new comment dynamically, the date stays in the `5-5-2012` format.  There are several other custom jQuery functions that act on repeating data that is now dynamically created by knockout (usually by selecting based on classes).

How can I apply these custom jQuery functions on dynamic data generated by knockout.js?

Comment: I wonder if monitoring DOM changes with something like .live works

Comment: @TomWijsman - sadly, live has been deprecated in favor of `.on` http://api.jquery.com/live/ Also, I don't know what event I would bind to.  What do you think a good event would be? I don't think `load` would work :/

Comment: Ah right, I see, haven't used it yet but just heard of it a while ago. You can find a [list of events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-types-list) where you would be looking for the DOM ones; perhaps something about modification of the character data, I doubt if it would change the sub tree itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option might be to use a custom binding handler which sends bound elements through your jQuery plugin, e.g.:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikebridge/Q9r86/4/

Another possibility might be to add a computed observable in your view model.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of being forced to use custom bindings...  Right now we are using a class to define who gets prettified.  +1 for the good example!  If I can't figure out anything else, I'll use this.

Comment: Hey, I used your idea and forked a new jsfiddle.  This might be a little more closely related to my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BGHhP/

Comment: Hope it gets you at least part of the way there.  I suspect the cleanest solution is to call it using a computed observable, because it would require less code to trigger the jquery transformation.  I also thought there might be a jquery trigger like .live or .on which would detect dom insertion---that'd be cleaner---but I don't think there is one.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the `.on` but so far I haven't gotten it to work :/

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to run some further custom logic on the generated DOM elements, you can use any of the afterRender/afterAdd/beforeRemove/beforeMove/afterMove callbacks described below.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        myItems: ko.observableArray([ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]),
        yellowFadeIn: function(element, index, data) {
            $(element).filter("li")
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
        },
        addItem: function() { this.myItems.push('New item'); }
    });
</script>
```

Source: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements

However, beware of the following note:

> If your goal is actually to attach other behaviors to new DOM elements when they have been added (e.g., event handlers, or to activate third-party UI controls), then your work will be much easier if you implement that new behavior as a custom binding instead